# How to make Actions object specific?

Tags: unity, actions

I have gun actions, and each part of the gun, has a specific action. However, when I export it into Unity, each object has every single animation, even if it never used that animation in Blender. What can I do, to make actions object specific?

Answer (score 0):

So the way blender exports normal object actions is that every action that can be applied will be applied to an object, I would recommend doing the animation with a rig, but you can also switch tick these boxes off and it should export as one animation.

[image]

Comment: it worked for me, but it wasn't what I wanted. I just didn't want an action, for every object in the blender file. I still wanted more than one action though.

Comment: Then you will have to use armatures and bones to animate the gun parts, all of the parts have to be under a single armature and connected to bones

Comment: Ah, alright then.